# best way to add data to block from code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, custom-options

I want to add a html page (which I made using code). How can I assign this   'test.phtml' file to a block named 'custom_block'. what is best way to do that ?
any help would be highly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create Helloworld.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return 'Magento';
    }
}
```

Call in layout xml

```
<referenceContainer name="
 <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Call layout in phtml helloworld.phtml

```
<h1><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: what will be path of Helloworld.php ?

Comment: And where its getting that block which I made on admin side?

Comment: if admin block then use  Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml 
like in Block/Adminhtml/Helloworld.php folder

Comment: get in view/adminhtml/templates/helloword.phtml

Comment: okay and  what will path of xml and helloworld.phtml ?

Comment: view/adminhtml/layout/adminsample_sampleone_index.xml

Comment: view/adminhtml/layout/adminsample_sampleone_index.xml

Comment: and lastly  phtml ?

Comment: /view/adminhtml/templates/helloworld.phtml